# ZSH evaluate history within a function?

Tags: command-line, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to get my shell to be *extra* fancy, and what I'd like is for certain pieces of the prompt to disappear if commands haven't been used in the past X commands. So for instance, I'd like to have RVM only appear in my prompt if I've used rvm in the past hundred commands. I wrote this functions:

```
function check_history() {
  setopt XTRACE
  local depth=$2
  local check_string=$1

  for i in $(seq 1 $depth); do
    local hist_string=!-${i}:0
    if [[ $hist_string == *${check_string}* ]]; then
      return 0
    fi
  done
  return 1
}
```

However, based on testing so far, `!-${i}` gets evaluated at function definition time, rather than on each execution. I tried putting it in single quotes, or using `eval`, and couldn't really get much progress.

So..  is it possible to get these to evaluate on function execution? I tried looking into `fc`, which the man pages cryptically reference, but I can't make heads or tails of how to use `fc`.

Comment: Give this a try: `hist_string=${${(z)$(fc -l -${i} -${i})}[2]}`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks [mpy](https://superuser.com/users/195224/mpy) - that got me on the right track.

Here's what I ended up with:

```bsh
local rvm_ruby='$(rvm_prompt_timed)'

function check_history() {
  local depth=$2
  local check_string=$1
  if [[ "${depth}" == "" ]]; then
    depth=-10
  fi

  fc -l -m "*${check_string}*" $depth 2&>1 > /dev/null
}

function rvm_prompt_timed() {
  check_history rvm -20
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "%{$fg[red]%}‹$(rvm-prompt i v g)›%{$reset_color%}"
  fi
}

PROMPT="╭─${user_host} ${current_dir} ${rvm_ruby}${git_branch}${tf_prompt}${kube} ${return_code}
╰─%B$%b "
```

Now when I haven't used rvm in 20 commands, it disappears from my prompt!